# Alias for listing top file and directory consumption - shortest way?

Tags: bash, ksh, alias

```
function isaix { echo "alias d='du -sm -- * 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -20'" >> ~/.kshrc; }
function islinux { echo "alias d='du -sm -- * 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -20'" >> ~/.bash_profile; }
OSTYPE="`uname`"; if echo "${OSTYPE}" | grep -iq aix; then isaix; fi; if echo "${OSTYPE}" | grep -iq linux; then islinux; fi
```

The previous lines create a "d" alias that lists the top 20 files, directories by size.

**Question**: How to make these long lines shorter? (The OS type detection or any other part)

Comment: why not have a function in both .kshrc and .bash_profile that does the same job -> function d { du -sm ....}

Comment: I don't want to make a big mess, only insert the needed thing where it is really needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
OSTYPE="`uname`"
OSTYPE="${OSTYPE,,}"
case "$OSTYPE" in
    *aix*)
        target=~/.kshrc
    ;;
    *linux*)
        target=~/.bash_profile
    ;;
esac
if [ -n "$target" ]; then
    echo "alias d='du -sm -- * 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -20'" >> "$target"
fi
```

Comment: `ksh` throws a syntax error on this code.  The question requires an answer for `ksh` as well as `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the shell's command expansion `$(...)` to switch the output file name.

This code checks only for aix.  The default behavior updates the `.bashrc`.

```
echo "alias d='du -sm -- * 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -20'" >> $( case $(uname) in *[aA][iI][xX]*) echo ~/.kshrc;; *) echo ~/.bashrc;; esac )
```

Or, split lines for readability:

```
rcfile=$( case $(uname) in *[aA][iI][xX]*) echo ~/.kshrc;; *) echo ~/.bashrc;; esac )
echo "alias d='du -sm -- * 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -20'" >> $rcfile
```

Comment: That is case-sensitive.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Thanks.  I think it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

A more compact version (valid in ksh and bash) is:

```sh
typeset -l ostype
ostype="$(uname)";
cmd="alias d='du -sm -- * 2>/dev/null |sort -nr |head -n 20'"

case "$ostype" in
    *aix*)     echo "$cmd" >> ~/.kshrc; ;;
    *linux*)   echo "$cmd" >> ~/.bash_profile; ;;
esac
```

Comment: `ksh` throws a syntax error on this code.  The question requires an answer for `ksh` as well as `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

An even shorter answer but a little more cryptic (works in bash and ksh):

```sh
typeset -l ostype; ostype="$(uname)"
cmd="alias d='du -sm -- * 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -20'"

case $ostype in
    *linux*) a=ba;;
    *aix*)   a=k;;
esac
a="${a:+~/".${a}shrc"}"
${a:+false} || echo "$cmd" >> "$a"
```